# SwiftyDropbox batchUploadFiles vs upload

Tags: swift, core-data, dropbox, swiftydropbox

I am uploading a large amount of photos and annotations to dropbox using the swiftyDropbox sdk. I want to update the UI to reflect the upload status of each item which is stored in coreData. My understanding of batchUpload is that you pass it an array of URLs and it uploads them asynchronously. I would like to use batch upload but I am not sure how to tell when a certain item is finished with batchUpload since it is operating on an array of URLs. Is there a way that I can use batchUpload, versus just iterating over the array with the upload function?

It seems that upload will would be the correct solution as I can just add each item to background thread asynchronously and update each one as they finish. Looking for arguments to persuade me either way.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and read [ask] for tips how to write a good question. You can [edit] your question with a [example] showing what you have already tried and what part is not working. This will help others answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `batchUploadFiles` method in the SwiftyDropbox method is advantageous as only has to take one lock to upload the entire batch of files. It only calls [the response block](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox/blob/d67e3cb255a7a71c59b5dc5d550bf6e2a0ebf5ca/TestSwiftyDropbox/IntegrationTests/TestClasses.swift#L60) once the entire batch is done though, and the files are committed in a batch, so you wouldn't see individual uploads being completed one by one. You instead get the result for each all together at the end.

If you do need to be able to see individual file uploads completed one by one for whatever reason, you would need to use individual upload calls, but that has the disadvantage of not batching the uploads, so you're more likely to run in to lock contention.